# Is there a way to omit a package or library from being minified or ignored by SWC?

Tags: next.js, bundling-and-minification, swc, swc-compiler

So I am building an audio chatroom in Next.js. For the chatting and calling features, I am using [Agora](https://www.agora.io/en/) that makes use of the `agora-rtm-sdk` [agora-rtm-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-rtm-sdk) and `agora-rtc-sdk-ng` [agora-rtc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-rtc-sdk-ng) packages.
So when building locally, everything works well.

The issue comes in when I deploy to Vercel or any other hosting platform.

The `agora-rtm-sdk` is not called at any point in my code, however the `agora-rtc-sdk-ng` works well

After struggling for days, I figured out the issue was in the bundling using [SWC](https://swc.rs/docs/getting-started).

This is my next.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  '@mui/material',
  '@mui/system',
  'agora-rtm-sdk',
  'agora-rtc-sdk-ng',
]);

module.exports = withTM({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true, //However setting swcMinify: true causes rtm to not work
  images: {
    domains: ['mydomainname.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com', 'localhost'],
  },
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },

  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      '@mui/styled-engine': '@mui/styled-engine-sc',
    };
    config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups = {
      common: {
        name: 'common',
        chunks: 'all',
      },
    };
    return config;
  },
});
```

So I got it to work by setting `swcMinify:false` 
However, this was just a band-aid solution and makes the app slow.

How can I omit the `agora-rtm-sdk` from being minified while minifying the rest of the app or how can I make sure that my package is not being "swallowed" by SWC?
Any help will be appreciated